# cast object to List<T>

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a MVVM Project one view has a grid that allow multiselect,

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGridBodegas" ItemsSource="{Binding MyLis}" Grid.Row="1">
     <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding _MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=DataGridBodegas,Path=SelectedItems}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
      </i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static resources:Labels.ACOPIO_SeleccioneBodegas}" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding StrNombreBodega}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}"/>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

At VM I have a ICommand

```
public override void CommandSelectionChange(object p)
{            
    MyList.RemoveAll(x=> x.IntIdBodega != -1);
    MyList = p as List<Merlin_INV_Bodegas>; // Allways return Null 
}
```

If I take a look into `p object` It is a `SelectedItemCollection` that has elements of my target type, but if try to cast as this

```
(List<TargetType>)p // Throw exception 
p as List<TargetType> // Allways return null 

foreach( TargetType t in p)
{
} // Throw exception
```

My questions are
How can I cast **p** properly to my  List?

Comment: Have you tried with `((TargetType[])p).ToList();`. Keep in mind that the array is copied inside the list this way.

Comment: An array is not a list.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria No. but I'm trying now

Comment: Why are you removing items from MyList? You immediately replace it with a new list, so this has no effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Linq `ToList()`:

```
List<TargetType> list = ((TargetType[])p).ToList();
```

Or else use the `List<>` constructor:

```
List<TargetType> list = new List<TargetType>((TargetType[])p);
```

If it is a `SelectedItemCollection`, you need to cast it as an IList first:

```
List<TargetType> list = ((System.Collections.IList)p).Cast<TargetType>().ToList();
```

Comment: This solutions throw an invalid cast.

Comment: Then `p` is not really an array of `TargetType`. You need to update your question with some screenshots of your debugging/inspector, or some concrete information about the classes and types involved

Comment: Tks @RGraham you are right really it is a SelectedItemCollection, the correction was made on my post.

Comment: Updated answer for `SelectedItemCollection`

Answer (score 2):

This is because `DataGrid.SelectedItems is of type IList` not generic `IList<T>`.
So you will have to typecast in IList

```
var collection = p as IList  

foreach( var item in collection)
{
    var myitem = (TargetType)item;
}
```

Comment: Tks a lot for your help. This answer is ok. but @RGraham directly cast the list thats why i market his solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since all you're doing is a `foreach` over the list, I'd suggest you cast to `IEnumerable` (or `IEnumerable<TargetType>`) instead. Using the simplest possible type/interface that you can is a good way of making your code more reusable and understandable.

If you're having trouble casting because the type being passed isn't what you think it is (which seems likely given the comments here so far), I'd suggest you put a breakpoint on the first line of your method, and inspect the value of `p` in the debugger. That way you can be sure of what's actually being passed.